# Textmate broke my Java? Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, macos, textmate

I ran a Java program using TextMate on OS X once and I can't use Java anywhere else anymore.
On the simplest program, I get:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   Gateway (wrong name:
>   org/mcgill/telecom/Gateway)

Whether I use `javac -classpath . Gateway.java, java -classpath . Gateway` or Eclipse or Netbeans.

The exact same program can still run in TextMate using cmd-R, but nowhere else.
What happened to my Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I highly doubt that a text editor did that.

Anyway, `java -classpath . Gateway` wouldn't work if that class is in the package `org.mcgill.telecom` (which the folder structure suggests).

Try `java -classpath . org.mcgill.telecom.Gateway` instead from the folder where the `org` folder can be seen.

Here's what you can do to test it.

- go to a `temp` folder and create this folder structure: `org/mcgill/telecom`;
- create a file called `Gateway.java` in the `telecom` folder;
- copy the contents below in your `Gateway.java` file;
- open a command prompt and navigate to your `temp` folder;
- execute `javac org/mcgill/telecom/Gateway.java`
- execute `java -classpath . org.mcgill.telecom.Gateway`

This is what I get:

```
bart@hades:~$ cd Temp/
bart@hades:~/Temp$ ls
org
bart@hades:~/Temp$ javac org/mcgill/telecom/Gateway.java 
bart@hades:~/Temp$ java -classpath . org.mcgill.telecom.Gateway
Oi, it works!
bart@hades:~/Temp$
```

Here the Gateway class:

```
package org.mcgill.telecom;

public class Gateway {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Oi, it works!");
  }
}
```